# Adjust table to fit within the page

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I am generating a table but I dont know why it's getting out of the page!

```
    [\begin{tabular}{|*{3}{l|}*{5}{c|}}
    \hline
     \textbf{Participant}  & \textbf{Systèmes}  & \textbf{Inventaires de sens}  & \textbf{Anglais}  & \textbf{Français}  & \textbf{Allemand}  & \textbf{Italien}  & \textbf{Espagnol}\\
    \hline
     \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_(WSD)-1}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-2}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
    \hline
    \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{2}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-3}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
    \cline{3-8}
     &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
    \hline
     \textbf{DAEBAK!}  & PD & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
    \hline
     \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-1 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
    \hline
     \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-2 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
    \hline
     \textbf{GETALP}  & WN-1 & WordNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
    \hline
     \multicolumn{3}{|l|}{\textbf{MFS}} & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
    \hline
\end{tabular}][2]
```

[image]

Comment: you are (mis)using tabularx: you need longtable for multi-page tables. If you do need tabularx for single-page tables, they must include an X column. (it is not an error not to have X but tabularx can do nothing for such a table, you could use teh standard `tabular` in that case)

Comment: tabular or tabularX dont change anything .. it did not get me what i want!

Comment: No as I say, what you want is longtable. tabular and tabularx never break over a page.

Comment: so, i change tabular by longtable ?

Comment: So you should read the documentation on https://www.ctan.org/pkg/longtable and you will learn how to do that.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your table is too wide for the page. You will have to rotate it or reformat it completely. You could also try to reduce each column with `p{...cm}` columns or by reducing the font size, but this will not help for good readability.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\begin{sidewaystable}
    \centering
    \caption{Your caption here}
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}*{5}{S[table-format=2.0]}}
        \toprule
        \textbf{Participant}  & \textbf{Systèmes}  & \textbf{Inventaires de sens}  & \textbf{Anglais}  & \textbf{Français}  & \textbf{Allemand}  & \textbf{Italien}  & \textbf{Espagnol}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_(WSD)-1}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-2}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-3}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{DAEBAK!}  & PD & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-1 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-2 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & WN-1 & WordNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{MFS} & &  & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}   
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: but i dont what it to be like this! is there anything else to do to make it straight

Comment: @batitamohamedali I named four possible modifications. You will have to decide. I can't make your page bigger. Sorry, but you will find everything somewhere around here. If you can't get your desired approach working, you could ask a clearer question on this very problem.

Answer (score 2):

If a table is too wide you just have to make it narrower. In this case the width was dominated by the headings so:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\hd[1]{\textbf{\begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}#1\end{tabular}}}
\begin{document}

\centering

X\dotfill X

    {\setlength\tabcolsep{5pt}
    \begin{tabular}{*{3}{l}*{5}{S[table-format=2.0]}}
        \toprule
        \hd{Participant}  & \hd{Systèmes}  & \hd{Inventaires\\ de sens}  & \hd{GB}  & \hd{FR}  & \hd{DE}  & \hd{IT}  & \hd{ES}\\
        \midrule
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_(WSD)-1}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-2}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \multirow{3}{*}{\textbf{UMCC}}  & \multirow{3}{*}{$\mathrm{DLSI\_ (WSD)-3}$}  & BabelNet  & 8  & 10 & 12 & 14 & 16\\
        &   & Wikipédia  & 12 & 15 & 18 & 21 & 24\\
        &   & WordNet & 16 & 20 & 24 & 28 & 32\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{DAEBAK!}  & PD & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-1 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & BN-2 & BabelNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{GETALP}  & WN-1 & WordNet & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \addlinespace
        \textbf{MFS} & &  & 36 & 45 & 54 & 63 & 72\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}  

\end{document}
```

Comment: I just used `\resizebox` and my table fits _horizontally_, but it's still a bit too large _vertically_ (I'm talking about fitting a Beamer slide). What is the simplest solution for this? Most of related questions on this site deal with former, not the latter (unless I haven't found them). Thank you!

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh A slide presentation is a very constrained form. that is the art of presenting to make information available in small enough chunks to be comprehended in one view. Don't apply automatic scaling, or ask random people on the internet to re-arrange the text. Write the slide with an amount of data appropriate to the format.

Comment: I realize that concept and agree. I'm not trying to pack lots of information on a single slide. This particular table almost fits, I just need to adjust either font size, or vertical space between the rows. I'm a beginner in LaTeX, hence my question.

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh use \small or whatever other size fits...

Comment: Does it matter, whether font size specification is located before `\begin{table}`, between `\begin{table}` and `\begin{tabular}`, or inside the `tabular` environment? Outside or inside of `\resizebox`?

Comment: @AleksandrBlekh don't use `\resizebox` (otherwise you'll just scale the table back up after making it small) if you put it inside the tabular it will just affect one cell, if you put it inside the {table} it will just affect that table, if you  put it inside {frame} it will just affect that frame, etc. It has the same scope as any font change like `\bfseries`

Comment: Thank you! I was able to fit the table by commenting out `\resizebox` and going from `\small` to `\tiny`. It's not ideal, but not that bad (the table occupies ~ 75% of the slide's surface). Since, as I understand there are no predefined font sizes between `small` and `tiny`, it seems that I have only two simple options: 1) leave it as is; 2) play with absolute numbers for font size specification (probably, not very elegant).